# Json string to a js array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a set of result which i have converted to Json using php json_encode function now i want this result as an array in js but I am not getting an idea to do this.

My PHP array is like this :

```
Array
(
    [latestRating] => Array
        (
            [456] => Anonymous has rated xxx9
            [457] => Anonymous has rated xxxx8
            [458] => Anonymous has rated xxxx3.5
        )

    [latestUser] => Array
        (
            [242] => xxxxhas just signed up
            [243] => xxxxxhas just signed up
            [244] => xxxxxxhas just signed up
        )

)
```

When i do a php json_encode function on this i get following string

```
{"latestRating":{"456":"Anonymous has rated mermaidbl00d 9","457":"Anonymous has rated GeorgiaHallx 8","458":"Anonymous has rated smithjhon 3.5","459":"Anonymous has rated Emilyxo 8.5","460":"Anonymous has rated leona 10","461":"Anonymous has rated leona 10","462":"Anonymous has rated W0rthlessliar 8","463":"Anonymous has rated Yousamsuck 9","464":"Anonymous has rated Aimeeerobbb 9","465":"Anonymous has rated lauramillerx 10","466":"Anonymous has rated tomwaz 1","467":"Anonymous has rated W0rthlessliar 1","468":"Anonymous has rated W0rthlessliar 1","469":"Anonymous has rated W0rthlessliar 1","470":"Anonymous has rated W0rthlessliar 1"},"latestUser":{"242":"rhiwilliamsx has just signed up","243":"W0rthlessliar has just signed up","244":"rebeccaronan has just signed up"}}
```

I tried using JSON.stringify and then jQuery.makeArray also to create an array out of it.
Then i tried eval('['+string+']') but none of them helped.

I am a newbie in Json couldnt find appropriate support as well.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead of `JSON.stringify`.
The fist is JavaScript's equivalent to PHP's `json_decode`, the latter equivalent to `json_encode`.

Note: If you're using `jQuery.ajax` with `dataType: 'json'`, then the parameter in the callback is already a decoded object.

In your code, the PHP "array" is not a JavaScript array, but an object.

Comment: Ok and I am sorry i didnt noticed we had that datatype option in the ajax too.I will get the Json string from there and how do we access it in the Js?When i alert it,it says an object.So i tried dot notation but was not successfull with that.I need it as an array.

Comment: As I said, the object you're passing is **not** an array, but an object. An example of your callback:  `function(data) {alert(data.latestRating['456']);}`.

Comment: Sorry Rob Im bit naive about this.json_encode gives out a json object of an array that is correct i got it.data.latestRating['456'] will give me the element.LatestRating is actually an index here having an array and i want to iterate over in in js so how do we do that?Sorry if this is a stupid question but i am bit confused.

Comment: Actually I had done it long time back I remember i used EVAl and got an array.Isnt it possible here Rob?

Comment: @techie_28 What do you expect? Update the question with the expected output and **relevant code** of your current attempt.

Comment: All I want that i get same array in js after ajax operation which is getting encoded here.I have the sample in the question.

Comment: @techie_28 Again: That thing in the question **is not a JavaScript array**! I have taken the liberty to visualise how the JavaScript object looks like **: http://jsfiddle.net/mHNHm/**. In the demo, a way to iterate through the object is also shown.

Comment: I do not understand the whole concept Rob and sorry if i am annoying.I want to know if I have 2 arrays in php and I merge them to form one how will i get it in the JS?

Comment: Rob..I have an another problem I do a[50] to create an index of 50 and a value only in it in Js.But it automatically creates all the indexes before 50..i wanted an array like this array(50=>'abc',98=>'pqr') Un ordered keys..i feed these keys and values to this array and i want it only hold it not creat indexes automatically.any idea?

Comment: @techie_28 Any code to show......? Come on, you keep asking questions, without showing any context. I don't like to mind-read that often.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt posted any code in last question coz i was able to solve it using your comments.For this one I have edited http://jsfiddle.net/mHNHm/2/ and left comment there.

Comment: .Did you got my point here Rob?This is the problem I am facing

Comment: @techie_28 That is not a stand-alone demo which illustrates your problem. With the right variable format, the following demo works fine..: http://jsfiddle.net/mHNHm/3/.

Comment: Rob please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522613/assigning-unordered-keys-to-a-js-array/10522658#10522658

Answer (score 2):

It should already be ready to go if you're using `json_encode()`, if not, use `JSON.parse()`. You can also check the PHP headers when you're echoing the data to include:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If it's coming back from an ajax response, just reference the object like so:

```
success : function(data) {
    console.log(data.latestRating);
}
```