# Assigning Unordered keys to a Js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting a random key value pair,Can i assign it to an array?

Its problematic here when I assign it like `arr[50] = 'abc'` it automatically creates the keys upto 50 like `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]` and so on.

and i wanted an array like this `arr[50=>'abc','40'=>'pqr','53'=>'lmn']`

I have it here

```
if(typeof(feedArr.latestRating) == 'object'){ 
                  jQuery.each(feedArr.latestRating,function(key,val){alert('key::'+key);
                    if(key in newRatingArr){ 
                    //delete the key if already exists
                      newRatingArr.splice(key,1);

                    }else{
                      //insert the key,value
                        newRatingArr[key] = val; //here is the problem occurs when key is 50 it automatically creates the indexes in the array upto 50 which i dont want
                       // alert('Key between::'+key);
                       // alert('Value between::'+newRatingArr[key]);
                      //newRatingArr.splice(key,0,val);
                    }
                    //alert(key); 
                  emptyRate = 0;

                  });
                }else{
                  emptyRate = 1;
                }
```

What can i do here?Please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Use an object `{}` instead of an array `[]`.

Objects can act as unordered key-value containers, which is what you seem to be needing here.

```
// somewhere...
var newRatingArr = {};

// your code.
var emptyRate = true;
if (typeof (feedArr.latestRating) == 'object') {
    jQuery.each(feedArr.latestRating, function (key, val) {
        newRatingArr[key] = val;
        emptyRate = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Will the other functions like SPLICE and all work on an object too? AKX?

Comment: my other array functions like concat and shuffle are use less if i use objects here AKX

Comment: But if you don't have array-like, contiguous data, then you shouldn't force it into an array...

Comment: Well i need to use my data which is most convenient to access in array form.Can I do that in objects?like deleting something from an object at certain index, inserting into it and iterating over it to show a result?

Comment: You can delete by a certain key (`delete x["foo"]`);, modify by keys (`x["foo"] = 1;` (or `x.foo = 1;`)) and iterate (in no specified order) (`for(var k in x) console.log(k, x[k]);`), yes.

Comment: Thats ok but can I merge them without overwriting the keys?My keys of each array indicates id's from different tables and needs to be merged in a single array.So i need to maintain duplicate indexes.

Comment: If you need a key-to-multi-value mapping, what about an object with arrays for values? `function kmvPut(mapping, key, value) { (mapping[key] || mapping[key] = []).push(value); }`